# Realizar una consulta en PHP mediante la obtencion de datos desde un formulario con un $_GET["valor"];

Tags: php, formularios

soy nuevo aqui, he dado algun que otro lenguaje en informática en el instituto y siempre me ha gustado, con el covid y mucho tiempo libre decidi hacer algun curso, estoy haciendo uno de php online siguiendo videos de hace unos 4-5 años.
Me he estancado en la parte de donde quiero introducir un datos por un simple formulario, y que ese dato see el que se reemplaze en la query.
Ejemplo: SELECT * FROM PERSONAS WHERE EDAD=22;
Lo que yo pretendo es que si por el formulario paso 10 la consulte se modifique a:
Ejemplo2: SELECT * FROM PERSONAS WHERE EDAD=10.

### No se si me he explicado bien =D Aporto codigo y capturas.

CODIGO DE pagina_busqueda.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PHP</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","php");
        mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");

        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Error al conectarse: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            exit(); 
        }


        $busqueda=isset($_GET["buscar"]);


        $consulta="SELECT * FROM PERSONAS WHERE ID='$busqueda'";

        $retorno_consulta=mysqli_query($connection,$consulta);

        while($imprime_consulta=mysqli_fetch_row($retorno_consulta)){
            for($i=0;$i<count($imprime_consulta);$i++)
                echo $imprime_consulta[$i]." ";
                echo "<br>";
        }

        mysqli_close($connection);
    ?>
</body>
</html>


----------
CODIGO formulario buscador.php

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="pagina_busqueda.php" method="get">
    <label>Buscar:<input type="text" name="buscar"></label>
    <input type="submit" name="enviando" value="Dale">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, cambia las capturas por el texto del código. Es más útil para entender el problema y ayudarte. Para el caso de código las capturas en vez de ayudar dificultan la comprensión. Pulsa en [edit] para hacer el cambio. Gracias... En cuanto a la pregunta, para recoger un valor, tienes que tener un `input` con el mismo y buscarlo por el `name`, haciendo algo así: `$elValor=$_GET["loQueHayaEnName"];` el `isset` sería para verificar que un elemento fue o no enviado desde el cliente no es para guardar los valores.

Comment: He creado un post bastante mas claro, echale un vistazo :)

Comment: [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/361425/error-undefined-index-al-recoger-datos-de-un-formulario) @A.Cedano