# Error Undefined Index al recoger datos de un formulario

Tags: php, mysql, formularios, get

Muy buenas a todos :) os cuento mi problemilla!!
Tengo dos archivos:
A)Un formulario donde se introduce un solo dato.
B)Una pagina que tiene conexión a una base de datos local (wamp). Esta consta de la conexión con la base de datos, una consulta mysql y un bucle que imprime todos los datos de dicha consulta.

El problema viene que tengo es el siguiente:
[image: Si accedo a la pagina principal me da este error]

Código de la pagina principal aquí:

```
<?php
        //Establece conexion con la BBDD
        $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","php");

        //Caracteres especiales español
        mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");

        //Recibe "un valor" de un formulario
        $busqueda=$_GET["buscar"];

        //Realiza la consulta
        $consulta="SELECT * FROM ARTICULOS WHERE SECCIÓN='$busqueda'";

        //Guarda el resultado de la consulta anterior
        $retorno_consulta=mysqli_query($connection,$consulta);

        //Impprime todos los atributos consultados
        while($imprime_consulta=mysqli_fetch_row($retorno_consulta)){
            for($i=0;$i<count($imprime_consulta);$i++)
                echo $imprime_consulta[$i]." ";
                echo "<br>";
        }

        //Cierra conexion con la BBDD
        mysqli_close($connection);
    ?>
```

Sin embargo si accedo al formulario y le paso un dato este si esta en la base de datos se ejecuta correctamente.
Aquí el código del formulario:

```
<body>
    <form action="busqueda.php" method="get">
    <label>Buscar:<input type="text" name="buscar"></label>
    <input type="submit" name="enviando" value="Dale">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Notice: Undefined index: submitbutton](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/308730/notice-undefined-index-submitbutton)

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que tu codigo lo hagas con consultas preparadas para darle mas seguridad con ello deberia quedar mas o menos de la siguiente manera

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ARTICULOS WHERE SECCIÓN=?";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$busqueda);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();
    $data = [];
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    /*TODO*/

?>
```

Considera que tu `data[]` ya va a traer todas las filas de la consulta, te recomiendo que para la interpretacion hagas algo asi:

```
foreach($data as $dat){
    echo $dat["key"]." ";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Recuerda que si tienes todas tus columnas desde una DB es mejor llamar cada una de ellas desde la interpretacion para tener mejor control de los datos.